# Insert LaTeX table in .Rnw file using RStudio

Tags: latex, knitr, rstudio

I am using RStudio and writing an .Rnw file to include LATEX and R codes. There is a table to be inserted, and I use standard LATEX codes within the .Rnw file, like

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{SUMMARY}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
\toprule
Data & stat1 & stat2 & stat3 & stat4 & stat5 \\
\midrule

itme1 & 36.101954 & 45 & 0.825500 & 0.220198 & 0.293448 \\
item2 & 51.828572 & 45 & 0.224900 & 0.499718 & 0.690064\\
item3 & 53.187455 & 45 & 0.188100 &  0.133086 & 0.603072 \\
item4 & 61.513952 & 45 & 0.051300 & 0.002566 & 0.014714 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}
```

However, when I click "Compile PDF" in RStudio, there is error message. I searched online about inserting tables in .Rnw file, and got the result of using `xtable` package. Can I use standard LATEX codes for doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You would be better off showing your actual code.  You could reduce it to a minimal example but for example you don't mention whether or not your "first row contents" are generated through R code or if you're just inserting everything manually...

Comment: @Dason: thanks, I've edited the post to be complete.

Comment: You're using `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` - this implies you're using the booktabs package.  Did you remember to include `\usepackage{booktabs}` in your preamble?

Comment: @Dason: yes, I included that package in my preamble, so that may not be the problem...

Comment: Then you should definitely post the errors you're getting because I can compile that just fine.  It wouldn't hurt to post the results of running `sessionInfo()` either.

Comment: @Dason: thanks for your comments :) The error message produced by RStudio is quite meaningless: it says missing "$" for several places, but in fact (after double checking) there is no such error. I am just curious whether it is eligible to include standard LATEX codes of tables in an .Rnw file.

Comment: Then the answer is yes - you can.  It sounds like your errors might be coming from somewhere else in the code?  I don't know but I don't get errors with just that table.  It's impossible to diagnose exactly what is wrong without seeing your full document though so... good luck?

Comment: @Dason: thank you so much for trying it out for me. I put the code in a new Rnw file and run Compile PDF, and still got the same error message of missing "$". In fact, there is even no $ inside my file...Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: This is getting to be way too much for just the comments but I'll make a few notes- "missing $" typically means that you're using some command that needs to be inside of a math type environment (so typically inside of `$ _your_commands_here $`.  Have you tried just starting at the absolute basics in your document and gradually building it up until you reach an error?  If you try to run the entire document without going through this process it can be harder to track down the errors but if you can say "I know up until this point there isn't a problem" then you have a better chance of finding it.

Comment: @Dason: yes, I tried to remove the table environment, and then everything compiles without error. There also seems to be no problem in the latex grammar of the table, so just curious what went wrong...anyway, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to "whether we can insert raw latex codes for making tables in the .Rnw file" is YES. I finally find out that the error comes from the underscore: if your column name include a `_`, then you need to write `\_`. Otherwise, when you click compile PDF in RStudio, there will be error messages produced (and it is extremely hard to debug!)

Comment: Ah... well you didn't have that as part of the original question otherwise I probably could have saved you some time ;)

Comment: @Dason: yeah...I just found that error, because when I use the R package `xtable` to generate the latex code, then I saw the only difference is the `_`! Thanks for watching this post ;)